# Is there a reference of default kubectl column templates?

Tags: output, kubectl

Is there a way to get from `kubectl` the default template of the output, if not, is there an online resource for these?

It doesn't matter which format it outputs, I'm just interested in a reference of how the output is constructed from the objects kubectl queries.

#### What I already know

Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/#custom-columns) show how to construct **custom-columns** (there is also a go-template and jsonpath way of doing this) output from `kubectl`.

Using describe, or --output json or yaml I can get the full object list, and scoure that to assemble a similar output, but I want to write a simple tool that will add a column to existing output, for that I need a starting point of 'default output'.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm unsure how you would do this for default|built-in Resources (e.g. Pod, Deployment, Service). It may be possible to query the API server directly. For Custom Resources, The `CustomResourceDefinition` may include `additionalPrinterColumns` (see [Additional printer columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#additional-printer-columns)) and so, for CRDs, you can query the resource's CRD e.g. `kubectl get crd/{foo} --output=jsonpath="{.spec.additionalPrinterColumns}"` where `{foo}` is the name of the CRD.

Answer (score 1):

You piqued my curiosity.

This isn't an answer but hopefully it helps.

I tried the following to glean the API calls made by `kubectl`:

```bash
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces --v=9
```

And, the output contained the essence of the following (I'm using `kubectl proxy --port=8801` to simplify this):

```bash
curl \
--get \
--header "Accept: application/json;as=Table;v=v1;g=meta.k8s.io,application/json;as=Table;v=v1beta1;g=meta.k8s.io,application/json" \
http://localhost:8001/apis/apps/v1/deployments?limit=1
```

```
{
  "kind": "Table",
  "apiVersion": "meta.k8s.io/v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "4949817",
    "continue": "[redacted]",
    "remainingItemCount": 1
  },
  "columnDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "name",
      "description": "Name must be unique within a namespace. Is required when creating resources, although some resources may allow a client to request the generation of an appropriate name automatically. Name is primarily intended for creation idempotence and configuration definition. Cannot be updated. More info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names#names",
      "priority": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Ready",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "",
      "description": "Number of the pod with ready state",
      "priority": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Up-to-date",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "",
      "description": "Total number of non-terminated pods targeted by this deployment that have the desired template spec.",
      "priority": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Available",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "",
      "description": "Total number of available pods (ready for at least minReadySeconds) targeted by this deployment.",
      "priority": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Age",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "",
      "description": "CreationTimestamp is a timestamp representing the server time when this object was created. It is not guaranteed to be set in happens-before order across separate operations. Clients may not set this value. It is represented in RFC3339 form and is in UTC.\n\nPopulated by the system. Read-only. Null for lists. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata",
      "priority": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Containers",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "",
      "description": "Names of each container in the template.",
      "priority": 1
    },
  "rows": [...]
```

So, it's not entirely clear to me how `Deployment` is resolved to the `Table` kind (which I was previously unaware existed) but it appears this matches the print columns of an in-built Resource.

Aha! [Receiving Resources as Tables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#receiving-resources-as-tables)

Comment: Interesting, but those are just the 'descriptions' we don't get the mapping to the json structures. I'll try this out.

Comment: I mean, this is basicaly the equvalent of capturing the header of a tabluar output from `kubectl`. I got spoiled by `gcloud` cli, where I found that when giving a bad formatting argument, you get the default spewed to the console, and I could copy and expand on it. Looks like manual labor is the only option right now.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Google's `gcloud` is fully documented. You can lookup methods using [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and the details page documents the request and response types e.g. Kubernetes Engine API (`container`) [`projects.locations.list`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/list) returns [`ListClustersResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/ListClustersResponse) which is what you get from `gcloud container clusters list --log-http`.

Comment: I'm hoping someone more familiar with the Kubernetes implementation will provide an explanation for `kubectl`. Your question piqued my curiosity but I did admit I don't know the answer.